# How to implement cylindrical panorama in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, 360-panorama

How can I implement cylindrical panorama in react native that works for android and iOS both?

I found following libraries but none fulfills my requirement fully.

1. Pano (This supports spherical panorama).
2. react-native-google-vr-panorama (this only available for android).
3. React-VR (This is separate VR project. I  just need to implement one thing).
4. react-native-360 (This is available for iOS only.)